# NSolve not solving my transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving, functions

Would be grateful for your help in tackling this complex polynomial where I am trying to solve for `x`. When I run the code below, I get the message:

> value x of the domain argument should be Complexes, Reals, Algebraics, Rationals, Integers, Primes or Automatic.

What would be the best way to address this?

```
sol = 
  NSolve[
    (g+0.4*(1/s)(Log[k*(1+x)*E^-r]/k +(r+s^2/2)-s)-0.16(1/s)(Log[k*(1+x)*E^-r]/k +(r+s^2/2)-s)^3+0.025(1/s)(Log[k*(1+x)*E^-r]/k +(r+s^2/2)-s)^5-0.003(1/s)(Log[k*(1+x)*E^-r]/k +(r+s^2/2)-s)^7) /
    (0.4*(1/s)(Log[k*(1+x)*E^-r]/k +(r+s^2/2))-0.16(1/s)(Log[k*(1+x)*E^-r]/k +(r+s^2/2))^3+0.025(1/s)(Log[k*(1+x)*E^-r]/k +(r+s^2/2))^5-0.003(1/s)(Log[k*(1+x)*E^-r]/k +(r+s^2/2))^7)==x, 
  0 < x < 10, 
  {x, 0.25}, x]
```

Comment: r, g, s, and k are other variables. I am trying to solve x in terms of these variables. I fixed the bracket issue but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Can you post the correction and that extra bit of information?

Comment: To solve the equation numerically, all parameters (i.e., `{r, g, s, k}`) must have numeric values. To use `Manipulate` to find solutions for various numeric values of the parameters, you need to specify the range of feasible values for these parameters.

Comment: Thank you Bob Hanlon, is there a command that would give me x in terms of these variables without specifying a range for them? I tried simplify before, but it was just taking forever...Thank you Moo, I am in Africa, and currently have to ask a colleague to run it for me every time I have a correction...So he emails me back the code in this form, in his code the bracket issue is correctly enclosed and he gets the same error.

Comment: anyone out there to help me with this problem? getting desperate here in Africa, but the result will help me solve a very interesting question. Would very much appreciate any suggestions. Bob Hanlon, what would be the syntax in specifying the range of feasible values for these variables? And how would I visualize the result? Thank you.

Comment: Your equation dose not involve polynomials by any definition of polynomial that I understand. NSolve does not support the syntax you are using. You might look at `FindRoot` which has a syntax closer to what you are giving `NSolve`. Unless you supply values for the all the undefined parameters, it will be impossible to give more specific help.

Comment: For me `NSolve` work fine: `r = 1; k = 2; s = 3; g = 4; e = 5;NSolve[eq, x, Reals]` give me: `{{x -> -0.973348}, {x -> -0.0412105}}`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to you especially Mariusz. You just inspired me to a solution for my paper!! I think an analytical answer to this equation is hopeless through manipulation (at least for me!), but perhaps there is an analytical solution through iterations of values for these 5 other parameters if for example for some of them there is convergence, e is the natural log.

Comment: Mariusz, could you kindly share with me the syntax you used? For some reason my colleague could not get the right form? Also, is there a command that would show me the steps used by Mathematica to arrive at the solution? Or what would be the most simplified expression just in terms of x after plugging these values...